# C OpenSSL: How to get X509_STORE_CTX from X509_STORE?

Tags: c, openssl, x509certificate, x509

I have a X509_STORE* pointer, my goal is to get its associated X509_STORE_CTX* pointer. May I know how to do this? I cannot get access to where initialize the X509_STORE_CTX*.

probably this is a simple question, but I check the OpenSSL manual API and its related header file again and again, not find any API could do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single `X509_STORE` can be used/shared by an unlimited number of `X509_STORE_CTX`, but most of the time isn't used/referenced by any, so an API to get "its ... pointer" makes no sense and does not exist.

This (not at all coincidentally) reflects a similar, but inversely named, difference at the `SSL` module (libssl) level. An `SSL_CTX` object defines security parameters that can be used by any number of connections each implemented as an `SSL` object. In the original design, the `SSL_CTX` owns an `X509_STORE` representing the truststore -- the set of roots (or other anchors if PARTIAL_CHAIN is used) used to validate peer certs and potentially to build out 'own' chains -- which you can modify using the `CTX` APIs like `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` or you can get the (automatically created) store with `SSL_CTX_get_cert_store` and modify it or create your own and install it with `SSL_CTX_set_cert_store`. OTOH each `SSL` dynamically creates its own `X509_STORE_CTX` while validating or sending a cert; no `X509_STORE_CTX` exists at other times. In 1.0.2 up an `SSL` by default uses the `SSL_CTX` store but you can override with `SSL_set[01]_{verify,chain}_cert_store`.

When you create an `X509_STORE_CTX` you identify the `X509_STORE` to use with `X509_STORE_CTX_init`. When you `_free` it this use/reference is terminated.